# 'querySelectorAll' não funciona

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estava fazendo um teste que ao clicar-se o botão todos 'p' devem ficar vermelhos. Alguem sabe o que está errado?

```js
function test() {
 document.querySelectorAll('p').style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>ola</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>teste</h1>
 <br>
 <hr>
 <p>ola</p>
 <p>oi</p>
 <p>qwerty</p>
 <button onclick="test()">testes</button>
 <script src="teste.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` devolve um array(conjunto) de elementos. É necessário usar um ciclo ou modificar um em particular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como o amigo tinha dito a cima, para funcionar, você terá que fazer assim...

```js
let elemento = document.querySelectorAll('p')

// Pega apenas o primeiro do array
elemento[0].style.color = 'red';

// pega todos

for(let i = 0; i < elemento.length; i++){
    elemento[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<h1>teste</h1>
 <br>
 <hr>
 <p>ola</p>
 <p>oi</p>
 <p>qwerty</p>
```

Comment: Poderia ter feito o mesmo c/ getElements ByClassName?

Comment: Apenas não entendi o que é o 'let'

Comment: @nelson450 Sim, funciona tambem para ClassName. Let é um novo padrão do ES5. basicamente é uma declaração de var. você pode subistituir por var

Comment: @nelson450 Let está restrito ao escopo de bloco, normalmente sializado por {  }. Enquanto var se não me engano é global. Isso provavelmente deve criar muita diferença de memória consumida, mas posso estar errado sobre o motivo real disso

Answer (score -2):

let é uma declaração de variável que vai ser utilizado apenas dentro do escopo do bloco, enquanto o var é uma variável global, foi criado para evitar confusões em outros escopo de bloco, já que se uma variável com o mesmo nome for utilizada ela já estará atribuída.

Comment: Benvindo ao StackOverflow em português! Embora correta, a resposta é um complemento a outra resposta e não a pergunta do tópico. Então deveria estar no comentário.

Comment: É que eu sou novo por aqui, vou me atentar!!!

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer publicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), mas, até lá, escreva apenas respostas que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/392779)